# How do i delete the second Header in the picture?

Tags: angular, typescript, header

i have a little problem. As you can see, in the picture my Header is shown twice on the site /printservice. I wrote in my app.component.ts this code:

[enter image description here][1]if ( this.routername == "/login" || this.routername == "/admin" || this.routername == "/printservice" || this.routername == "" ) {
this.showHeader = false;

This code works, except for printservice.

My app.component.html looks like this:

````
    <!-- Header-->
    <div class="header" *ngIf="showHeader">
        <router-outlet name="headerOutlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <!-- Routeroutlet-->
    <div class="outlet">
        <!-- activates the method on the ts file -->
        <router-outlet  (activate)="componentAdded($event)"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icGwz.png
````

Comment: What version of Angular is this? I've never seen routes being setup like that.

Comment: it is the newest version 10.1.6

Comment: Are you sure that if condition works as you expect? Looking at the image, it seems it's returning true

Comment: hmm now that you are sayig it. On the admin and login site the header appears in the background ( in the background because the admin and login site have a picture). But i could swear it worked.

Comment: Could also be a lifecycle issue. Maybe the `this.routername` is not updated yet, therefore using the previous routername in the condition. Login and Admin may work because you navigate to them from a page that is in the condition, e.g. you go from `""` to `/login` and you go from `/login` to `/admin`, but you might go from `/pagenotlistedincondition` to `/printservice`. You should print this.routername to see if it's the correct value before the condition.